# Copy from one google storage bucket to another while preserving ACL (Access rights)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have been using following command :

```
gsutil -m rsync -r gs://sourcebucket gs://destinationbucket
```

Yet, this does not preserve sourcebuckets access rights for each particular object in the storage.

Some of the objects in the source bucket are public. How can I preserve access rights, while copying to the destination bucket ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the rsync & cp commands don't copy the object ACL to the new object, and instead will use the default bucket ACL, You can override this behavior with the -p option